# Finding a basis of the polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a vector space $V$ of all polynomials $P(t)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}[t]$ of degree less than or equal to $n$ such that $P(a)$=$P'(a)$=$0$ for $a$  $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ fixed.

How should I proceed to find the basis and then the dimension?

Comment: You usually need to say what field you're working over. I assume here $\mathbb C$?

Comment: That's right, sorry..

Comment: What does the Taylor expansion of these polynomials at $a$ look like? Or: what happens if you change the variable $t$ for $s=t-a$? What do the conditions become? Or: what his the dimension of the intersection of two hyperplanes in a dimension $n+1$ vector space?

Comment: No. Setting $Q(s):=P(s+a)$, the conditions become $Q(0)=Q'(0)=0$. And I am sure you can find a basis for these. Then change the variable back.

Comment: Or recall or prove: $P(a)=P'(a)=0$ iff $P(t)$ is divisible by $(t-a)^2$, for a different approach.

Comment: I understand why $P(t)$ is divisible by $(t-a)$, but not why it is divisible by $(t-a)^2$. Can you explain me please?

Comment: So $P(t)=(t-a)Q(t)$ whence $P'(t)=Q(t)+(t-a)Q'(t)$ and so $Q(a)=0$...